# How can I earn the "...Without Bullets!" achievement?

Tags: achievements, just-cause-3

There is an achievement to Destroy every chaos object in a Military Base without weapons, grenades, or planted explosives.  How is this possible?  Am I suppose to melee fuel tanks?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your grappling hook can be used to pull down/apart any chaos objects, or sling explosive barrels into them. Alternatively, you can drive vehicles into things.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you, saves me from committing suicide several times haha

Comment: Another option: Get any Heat level (the enemies are attacking you) and you can stand on or near Chaos objects, and let the enemies destroy them for you with their bad aim.

Comment: Grappling hook note: It is much easier to destroy Chaos objects with the grappling hook once you get one or both of the grappling hook tether strength upgrades.

Answer (score 3):

The grappling hook is the easiest method and the easiest base to achieve this is Cima Leon: Silo. There are only a few chaos objects in the base and they are all easy enough to break with your hook.

The base is on the first island and the co-ordinates are N 40 41.334 E 5 43.546